# Error Moving WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I'm in the process of trying to move a WordPress site from "example.com/wordpress" to "newsite.com" and I've run into some considerable trouble.

I made a backup of the database and put a copy of all of the WP files onto the new host. I then tried to change the URL, but got a bunch of errors on the new page. I tried to revert back to the old site in the hopes getting everything in order again, but now everything redirects to the "new" site. My wp-config and database settings are all the same as they once were since I never deleted them off the old site. I've since deleted the files from the new site. The page is still redirecting and I can't access the dashboard login.

I'm completely at a loss right now, so I could really use some expert opinion. Thanks for any help that leads to a solution.

[Old Site Link](http://www.delindesign.com/excellence)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to phpmyadmin or any interface for your database you can go into the wp_options table and update rows 1 and 36. As jogesh_pi mentioned, the base url of your site is stored there, so you will need to update the database with your new path.

You can run this query in phpmyadmin and it will do it for you. Obviously replace the newsite url with your own.

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = 'http://www.newsite.com' WHERE option_name = 'siteurl' OR option_name = 'home'
```

Comment: You're a life saver, thank you. Changing row 1 allowed me to log-in to my wp-admin and change the site address. Thanks!

Comment: You will still need to run a database wide search and replace update for everything to work correctly.  Changing the siteurl and home options in the DB will fix any programmatically generated internal links (e.g. ones generated by PHP template functions) but any internal links, image/media embeds, etc within your post content itself will still reference the old URL.

Comment: Yes, definitely. @usefulbattery - you'll also want to check ennui's answer. You can inspect embedded media elements in your posts to verify URL paths are correct. In many cases, moving wp from dev envirenments can leave old url structures in place that technically work, but should be updated to the new site url.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run a database query that updates all instances of your old URL with your new URL.  The process is explained in detail in the [Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL).

I like to use [this very useful PHP script](http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) for running the database update automatically as it takes into account serialized strings which in certain cases can break widgets or plugins if they are not addressed.

Answer (score 1):

I always run into this issue, I use this plugin now to transfer wordpress sites: http://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/

But heres a quick fix:

1. Login to phpmyadmin, go to your database
2. Go to wp_options
3. Change these two options to your new url where my url's are the old ones:

[image]

[image]

If your wp-content folder is of the old site contents, it should pick up. But if your images dont show, use a URL changer plugin like this one: http://wordpress.org/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/

Comment: I ended up using Duplicator to get things finally ported over to the new site. A great tool and suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

it's just a simple query that helps you to transfer your wordpress site from old to new.

```
update  wp_options set 
    `option_value` = replace(`option_value`, 'example.com/wordpress', 'newsite.com');
```

beside this make sure about the file permissions and the database is same that you have used in the old site.